# Looking for an elegant way to search for many file extensions into a filename string

Tags: regex, perl, search, file-extension

I would like to find out if a file has a particular file extension, selected in a list of extensions.

I had this initial idea:

```
my $file = "filename.zip";
my @allowedExts = ( '.zip', '.tar.gz', '.tar.bz2' );

my $found = 0;
foreach $ext (@allowedExts) {
  if (index($file, $ext) != -1) {
    $found = 1;
    last;
  }
}

print "found" if ($found);
```

**Is there a simpler way to do that?**

Comment: You might get quite an unexpected behaviour using `index` to check file extension. Above code would also set `$found = 1` for `my $file = "filename.zip.testing.txt";`

Comment: It really depends how many filenames/extensions you are dealing with.  See File::Basename::fileparse to get a file extension from a filename.  Use a hash to store allowed file extensions, then use `exists` to check if the extension is present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`index` is not a good idea here, you might get very unexpected behaviour if the extension itself is found somewhere in the middle of filename.

Also: **ALWAYS** `use strict` and `use warnings`

Regex matching at the end of the string will be a better solution here, see the code below.
`$` is a metacharacter used to *match the end of the line (or before newline at the end)*

```
#!/usr/bin/perl                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file = "filename.zip";
my @allowedExts = ( '.zip', '.tar.gz', '.tar.bz2' );

my $found = 0;
foreach my $ext (@allowedExts) {
    if ($file =~ /\Q$ext\E$/) {
        $found = 1;
        last;
    }
}

print "found" if ($found);
```

You will probably get loads of other ideas for solving this. As always with perl: TIMTOWTDI.

EDIT:
As @ikegami suggested, regex should be escaped so that the dot is not treated as metacharacter but literal match, `\Q` and `\E` escape metacharacters in the regex.

Comment: owwwwww. You're going to recompile each regex for each file name! Also, `unzip` would be detected as a `.zip` file even though it isn't.

Comment: You're right @ikegami, added metaquoting to regex, thank you for pointing out! As per recompiling the regex... OP was not interested in super speed performance of it but simplicity which is a subjective measure.

Answer (score 4):

If you truly have many extensions (not just three), avoid the loop by finding the extension first, then checking a hash:

```
my $file = "filename.zip";
my @allowedExts = ( '.zip', '.tar.gz', '.tar.bz2' );

my %allowedExts;
@allowedExts{@allowedExts} = ();
my (undef, $ext) = split /(?=\.)/, $file, 2;

my $found = $ext && exists $allowedExts{$ext};
```

The above will treat everything in the filename starting from the first `.`; if you have `.` in the filename *before* what you want to find as an extension, you can assemble all the extensions into a single regex:

```
my $file = "filename.zip";
my @allowedExts = ( '.zip', '.tar.gz', '.tar.bz2' );

my $found = $filename =~ ( join( '|', map quotemeta, @allowedExts ) . '\z' );
```

Comment: That's a very loose definition of an extension. Most implementation I've seen allows for "." to be used in the non-extension part of the file name.

Comment: .tar.gz as an extension is an equally loose definition.  but yes, this won't work if you expect to find some.filename.zip as a .zip.

Answer (score 1):

```
use List::Util qw(first);

my $file = "filename.zip";
my @allowedExts = map qr/\Q$_$/, ( '.zip', '.tar.gz', '.tar.bz2' );

my $found = first { $file =~ /$_/ } @allowedExts;
```

Answer (score 0):

Anther approach is to use regular expressions.

Build the regex:

```
my @allowedExts = qw( .zip .tar.gz .tar.bz2 );
my $pat = join '|', map quotemeta, @allowedExts;
my $re  = qr/$pat\z/;
```

Use it:

```
my $file = "filename.zip";
print "Found\n" if $file =~ $re;
```